# conda install -c anaconda lxml not working on a work laptop

Tags: windows-10, command-line, python, anaconda

my personal laptop died, so I'm trying this on a work laptop temporarily until I can get a new laptop.  I was able to install python fine but when I started to repeat a process of installing the addons that I used before, I can't get the same command to work on this laptop.  I have a feeling because I may not be set as an administrator on the laptop.  From the command prompt, I entered "conda install -c anaconda lxml"

**c:>conda install -c anaconda lxml
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I also added the directory to the environmental variable path.

I am trying to help a friend with something so I am trying to help as fast I can, because I will probably need to write a lot of code for my friend.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to install it with this
py -m pip install lxml

(I had a tiny insight, and had a "what the heck" moment, so I just gave it a shot and it seemed to work to my absolute surprise.)

Here's the information that showed up.

**:>py -m pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
Downloading lxml-4.6.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.5 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 3.5 MB 939 kB/s
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.6.3**